# How to verify SNMP is working on Windows 2003/2008 servers?

Tags: windows, snmp

I've installed SNMP on my environment of Windows Server 2003/2008 and configured with group policy to allow our monitoring system to SNMP READ and TRAP with our custom community string.  I have a handful of servers that are failing in the monitoring system with no response eventhough they appear to be configured and running.

What Windows-based tools can I use to troubleshoot connectivity and configuration?  I would like to do things like SNMP ping, get data (snmpwalk?), or force a trap.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Verify that the server is listening on the SNMP port (161): `netstat -an |find /i "listening"`

Unofficial Windows net-snmp binaries: http://www.elifulkerson.com/articles/net-snmp-windows-binary-unofficial.php

Provides standard tools like snmpget and snmpwalk.

`snmpwalk -v 1 -c community-here 127.0.0.1`

I'd recommend first verifying locally on the server that SNMP is working before continuing to troubleshoot on your monitoring clients.
...

Answer (score 1):

Under Firewall Rules, Inbound Rules, SNMP Service (UDP In) w/ profile Private,Public the Scope defaults to the "Local subnet" which may not be the same subnet as your monitoring server.

Adjusting this rule worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To add to brent's answer I have recently discoverd [Getif](http://www.wtcs.org/snmp4tpc/getif.htm) which facilitates some SNMP verification as well as other network related tasks.